# gulp-typescript generating incorrect module path in singular file output

Tags: typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

Here's my project structure.

```
node_modules
js
  app
    app.ts
built_js
  app
    app.js <- compiled from js folder
```

I have a tsconfig.json that, when run via `tsc`, correctly generates module definitions like the following in app.js, the idea being there will be many files combined here:

```
System.register("app/app", ...
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "rootDir": "js",
    "outFile": "built_js/app/main.js"
}
```

However, whichever way I try to build my files using `gulp-typescript`, it generates the wrong System.register command, ignoring the rootDir property.

```
System.register("app", ...
```

gulpfile.js (both tasks generate the above):

```
var tsProj = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: typescript
});

gulp.task('tsc', () => {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(['js/**/*.ts'], {base: './js/'}).pipe(ts(tsProj));
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});

gulp.task('tscproject', () => {
    var tsResult = tsProj.src().pipe(ts(tsProj));
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
});
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?